# Why is the type parameter of this blanket trait implementation not considered to be constrained?

Tags: rust, types

I'm trying to understand how type constraints interact with associated types, and I've hit upon this case that I don't understand. I've read the RFC on unconstrained types in generic `impl`s, but I can't see how this fits into the list of disallowed things. Intuitively, I would expect that for any type implementing `Baz<T>`, this code would specify exactly one unambiguous `impl` of `Foo`. Am I wrong about that, or can the compiler just not make that leap of logic? If not, why not?

```
trait Foo {
    type Bar;
    fn foo(&self) -> Self::Bar;
}

trait Baz<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T, TBaz> Foo for TBaz
where
  TBaz: Baz<T>
{
    type Bar = T;
    fn foo(&self) -> Self::Bar {
        Baz::<T>::foo(self)
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=476fcf7df760066888c4c5853d43c11f))

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/lib.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<T, TBaz> Foo for TBaz
   |      ^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you are wrong because there is not one unambiguous `impl`. Assume a type `SomeType` that implements both `Baz<i32>` and `Baz<f32>`. What impl will we choose? What will be the value of the associated type `Bar` - `i32` or `f32`?

Formally (and from the compiler point of view), you are wrong because you are breaking [the rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/implementations.html#generic-implementations):

> Generic parameters *constrain* an implementation if the parameter appears at least once in one of:
>
> - The implemented trait, if it has one
> - The implementing type
> - As an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-types) in the [bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/trait-bounds.html) of a type that contains another parameter that constrains the implementation
>
> Type and const parameters must always constrain the implementation. Lifetimes must constrain the implementation if the lifetime is used in an associated type.

`T` appears neither in the implemented trait (`Foo`), nor in the implementing type (`TBaz`) or as an associated type. And it is a type parameter.

I think your intuition failure was by the assumption that `TBaz` will implement `Baz` only for one type, probably by a generic implementation `impl<T> Baz<T> for TBaz<T>`. But this is not enforced by the language. There is a mechanism that enforces that - associated types. If `T` was an associated type of `Baz` it was fine.

Comment: Thanks; that's a key insight. I think I was also interpering associated types as a sort of syntactic sugar for interacting with generic parameters -- sort of like TypeScript's `infer` -- and that there could therefore be a type that implemented both `Foo<Bar = i32>` and `Foo<Bar = f32>`. In hindsight, that's clearly wrong.